# Two way binding with EF and C# Winform with Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table call `Table1` with a lot of records and I would like to bind it to a `datagridview1` so I can perform update on `datagridview1`

The issue:  I only want to have a single record or records I would like to edit instead of all records available in `Table1`

```
var dataContext = new Entities();
dataContext.Table1.Load();
datagridview1.DataSource = dataContext.Table1.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I tried different approaches with `Select` & `SingleOrDefault`  like

```
datagridview1.DataSource = dataContext.Table1.Local.ToBindingList().Select(r=>r.ID==1) ;
```

There is no error but no record shown either.

Question: how could I select the records I would like to update but still keeping 2 way binding between EF source and my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
dataContext.Table1.Local.ToBindingList().Where(r=>r.ID==1).Select(r=> new YourClass(){id=r.ID, //and so on}).ToList();
```